# Need an xdg-open tweak

Tags: command-line, scripts, browser, xdg, xdg-open

I know that by running

```
watch -n 10 xdg-open https://duckduckgo.com
```

in the terminal, will open the specified site in a preferred browser at each 10 seconds. I am looking for a tweak which will close the tab in which the site is loaded after 5 seconds it loads. Briefly, I want to open and close a site at regular intervals from a terminal and should be able to stop the process whenever I need. Can anybody help me with this, please?

*P.S. I have already tried browser extensions and I am looking for command-line ways to do it.*

Comment: You can not close a tab from command line. This would wait 5 seconds and (gracefully!) close firefox: `sleep 5 && DISPLAY=:0.0 wmctrl -c "Firefox"`.

Comment: What if we browser the site using another tools?

Comment: @Ravexina Please give explanation

Comment: An example can be using command line tools like `curl https://duckduckgo.com` in a loop use `curl` to open your specific url then wait for x second and do it again.

Comment: @Ravexina run in terminal?

Comment: Yeah you can run it on terminal.

Comment: Not getting the idea, could you please explain more?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I suggest:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
 curl https://duckduckgo.com &> /dev/null
 sleep 5
done
```

Every 5 second it will opens the "duckduckgo" website once.

You can stop the process using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>

---

Save it in a file named `script.sh`, then run:

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

and to run it use:

```
./script.sh
```

Note that you don't get any output it just opens the URL once in every 5 second.

If you want to see the output you should remove `&> /dev/null`.

Comment: Should it be run through a text file or directly from the terminal?

Comment: Both is possible... you can save it in a file then run it like `bash filename`.

Comment: Saved it as 'xyz' and tried running by 'bash xyz', but nothing happens.

Comment: See my update...

Comment: It doesn't show this site open after removing '&> /dev/null' also. The output on the terminal is some HTML script I guess.